# Tile on the side of shower base

Tags: shower, tile, remodeling, thinset

I saw this at a hotel where they tile on the side of the shower base which is fiberglass:

[image]

[image]

My question is: Do I just tile directly on the side of the pan? How do I make the thinset to stick?

Thanks.

Comment: i do not think that the tiles are attached to fiberglass .... there is some other material underneath the shower pan

Comment: If you're going tile to fiberglass then I would use silicone based adhesive. One of the tile guys will come along with a specific product or method.

Answer (score 1):

The curb in this picture is about 3" wide. That is enough to put under the pan a piece of 2x4 (vertically) and screw a 1/2" thick hardie backer.  Then you can use thinset to attach tiles to the hardie backer.

Do not attach your tiles to a layer that can warp, expand, or shrink.  Your tiles will crack.

Answer (score 0):

You should always lay tile over backer board. If you are trying to attach tile to other surfaces, you can use a construction adhesive such as Power Grab. Place a generous amount on the back side of each tile piece. The tiles will be re-positionable for about 15 minutes. You will need to wait until the following day to grout the tile.

[image: Loctite Power Grab]